# Bad request when using axios to access google image search API

Tags: javascript, api, axios, google-custom-search

I want to search google for three images to display on my site.

I thought this was the minimum info the api needed to get the information but maybe I'm missing something.  Google isn't being very helpful on this.

```
const GOOGLE_API_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1';

async function google_image_search(searchTerm){
  const response = await axios({
    method:'GET',
    url:GOOGLE_API_URL,
    params:{
      q:searchTerm,
      num:3,
      searchType:'image',
      key:API_KEY,
    }
  });
  return response;
}
```

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }
        ],
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably need to provide `cx` in query as well. cx is your search engine id

Comment: Okay.  I set up a search engine and now I get the response with `searchInformation: {…}
​​​
formattedTotalResults: "0"
​​​
totalResults: "0"`  My ultimate aim here is to make a firefox extension that will allow a user to highlight text and display an image result in a tooltip above it.  I set up the engine to search google.com but maybe that was the wrong choice.  Would you agree?

Comment: try changing num value to 1 as initial and try again

Comment: `searchInformation: {…}
​​​
formattedTotalResults: "0"
​​​
totalResults: "0"` same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to set it to images in the control panel of the custom search engine in my google developer settings.